# How do I pass an interface to an adapter?

Tags: android, google-maps, interface

My setup involves a Googlemap view with a recyclerview superimposed in **MapviewFragment.class**. Any time the user clicks on an itemview (which contains data I am queried from Firestore), I need to reposition the camera to focus on that itemview's subsequent google map marker.

So to accomplish this I am passing the position of the clicked item from **RestaurantPickAdapter.class**, checking that against all of the markers via an index and then repositioning the camera. However, I have no idea how to pass the interface and even less so how to instantiate it.

Here is my *MapviewFragment.class* (it has 600 lines of code dealing with markers and polylines that I have excluded).

```
public class MapviewFragment extends Fragment implements
        OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener,
        RestaurantPickupAdapter.RestaurantRecyclerListener,
        GoogleMap.OnPolylineClickListener {

// This method below queries firestore and loads the recyclerview
private void listRestaurants(View pickupView) {
        restaurantItemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

        restaurantRecycler = pickupView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_pickup_recycler);
        restaurantRecycler.setHasFixedSize(true);
        restaurantRecycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(mapviewContext, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));

        Query restaurantQuery = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("Restaurant_Data").limit(LOAD_LIMIT);
        restaurantQuery.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    restaurantItemsArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            RestaurantItems restaurantItems = new RestaurantItems(document.getString("restaurantName"),
                                    document.getString("restaurantDescription"), document.getString("restaurantAddress"),
                                    document.getString("restaurantLogo"), document.getId(), document.getGeoPoint("geoPoint"));
                            restaurantItemsArrayList.add(restaurantItems);
                            Log.d(TAG, "menu items:" + restaurantItemsArrayList);
                        }
                    }

                    RestaurantPickupAdapter.RestaurantRecyclerListener restaurantRecyclerListener =

                    restaurantPickupAdapter = new RestaurantPickupAdapter(mapviewContext, restaurantItemsArrayList, // this is where I need to pass the interface);
                    restaurantRecycler.setAdapter(restaurantPickupAdapter);
}

// In this method the the camera is focused on the marker (i.e. location of a restaurant) that corresponds to the itemview (i.e. restaurant description)
 @Override
    public void onRestaurantClicked(int position) {
        String restaurantId = restaurantItemsArrayList.get(position).getRestaurantId();
        for (String markerRestaurantId : markerRestaurantIdArrayList) {
            if (markerRestaurantId.equals(restaurantId)) {
                googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(restaurantItemsArrayList.get(position).getGeoPoint().getLatitude() , restaurantItemsArrayList.get(position).getGeoPoint().getLongitude())), 600, null);
                break;
            }
        }
    }
```

Here is the RestaurantPickupAdapter.class

```
public class RestaurantPickupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RestaurantPickupAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder>{

    private Context adapterContext;
    private ArrayList<RestaurantItems> restaurantItemsArrayList;
    private RestaurantRecyclerListener restaurantRecyclerListener;

    public RestaurantPickupAdapter(Context adapterContext, ArrayList<RestaurantItems> restaurantItemsArrayList, RestaurantRecyclerListener restaurantRecyclerListener) {
        this.adapterContext = adapterContext;
        this.restaurantItemsArrayList = restaurantItemsArrayList;
        this.restaurantRecyclerListener = restaurantRecyclerListener;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RestaurantPickupAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(adapterContext);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item_restaurant_pickup, viewGroup,false);
        return new RestaurantViewHolder(view, restaurantRecyclerListener);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RestaurantPickupAdapter.RestaurantViewHolder viewHolder, final int i) {
        viewHolder.tvRestaurantName.setText(restaurantItemsArrayList.get(i).getRestaurantName());
        viewHolder.tvRestaurantAddress.setText(restaurantItemsArrayList.get(i).getRestaurantAddress());
        viewHolder.tvRestaurantDescription.setText(restaurantItemsArrayList.get(i).getRestaurantDescription());
        Glide.with(adapterContext).load(restaurantItemsArrayList.get(i).getRestaurantLogo()).into(viewHolder.tvRestaurantLogo);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return restaurantItemsArrayList.size();
    }

    class RestaurantViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
        public TextView tvRestaurantName, tvRestaurantAddress, tvRestaurantDescription;
        public ImageView tvRestaurantLogo;
        RestaurantRecyclerListener restaurantClickListener;

        public RestaurantViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, RestaurantRecyclerListener restaurantRecyclerListener) {
            super(itemView);
            tvRestaurantName = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_name);
            tvRestaurantAddress = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_address);
            tvRestaurantDescription = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_description);
            tvRestaurantLogo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.restaurant_logo);
            restaurantClickListener = restaurantRecyclerListener;

            itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            restaurantClickListener.onRestaurantClicked(getAdapterPosition());
        }
    }

    public interface RestaurantRecyclerListener{
        void onRestaurantClicked(int position);
    }
}
```

I cannot simply pass *this*, because inside the onSuccess/onComplete listener for firestore *this* refers to the query result.

Comment: `MapviewFragment.this` is probably what you want there since it implements the interface.

Comment: That solved the problem for me. If you answer the question, I can mark it correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be what you want:

```
restaurantPickupAdapter = new RestaurantPickupAdapter(
        mapviewContext, restaurantItemsArrayList, MapviewFragment.this);
```

Anonymous inner classes have reference to the instance of the class they are created in using that syntax.